# typeorm createConnection return Pending even with Await on MacOS with PG

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, macos, typeorm

MacOS Catalina 10.15.4

How to reproduce, simply install using quick guide

```
npm install typeorm --save
npm install reflect-metadata --save
npm install @types/node --save
npm install pg --save
npm install typeorm -g
typeorm init --name MyProject --database postgres
cd MyProject
npm install
npm start
```

It will simply return

```
➜  MyProject npm start

> MyProject@0.0.1 start /Users/sergecolle/work/eve/MyProject
> ts-node src/index.ts
```

When troubleshooting I found that neither the code in then and catch got executed. After modifying the code, to something like

```
const connection:Connection = await createConnection()
```

the connection will be in state Pending and then the program simply skip then and catch and terminate.

I have ask a friend to try it on his mac and he get the same issue.

there the package.json generated by the typeorm install

```
   "name": "MyProject",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "description": "Awesome project developed with TypeORM.",
   "devDependencies": {
      "ts-node": "3.3.0",
      "@types/node": "^8.0.29",
      "typescript": "3.3.3333"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "typeorm": "0.2.25",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
      "pg": "^7.3.0",
      "express": "^4.15.4",
      "body-parser": "^1.18.1"
   },
   "scripts": {
      "start": "ts-node src/index.ts"
   }
```

and the ormconfig.json

```
{
   "type": "postgres",
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": 5432,
   "username": "test",
   "password": "test",
   "database": "test",
   "synchronize": true,
   "logging": false,
   "entities": [
      "src/entity/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "migrations": [
      "src/migration/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
   }
}
```

and made sure a postgres db with those credential existed using the psql command.

The tsconfig.json generated

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": [
         "es5",
         "es6"
      ],
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "./build",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "sourceMap": true
   }
}
```

The lib and target seem a little old to support async/await. I tried updating it to es2017, es2018, and esnext but no luck

Comment: It seem to be a MacOS issue, while we were able to reproduce on Mac machine, the step above work perfectly fine on Linux.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It appears to be a problem with **pg** (node-postgres). As far as I can see, you're running version **7.3.0**. Try uninstalling **pg** with `npm uninstall pg --save` and then install it again with `npm install pg --save` . This will install the latest version (which for me was **8.2.1** )

Additional info: I had a project working fine on Ubuntu and then set it up on my MacBook, where I experienced the same issue. I also tried using ConnectionManager with different connection options and it still didn't work. The only thing that worked was the solution I mentioned above

Comment: I had the same issue, after upgrading pg version it started working, thanks

Comment: Spent 2 days trying to find solution to this problem and it was this simple!!! Thanks @badrain

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue on mac mini and macbook pro and getting 12.18.0 version of nodejs from the official website fixed the problem form me.